# How to fix dataframe interpreted $ as delimiter in the $text $?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, mathjax

I am loading many twitter text from database into dataframe. However, when there are multiple `$` in the original text, the dataframe will automatically interpreted the `$` as delimiter and transfer the text between these two `$` into a mathjax format. And the `$` disappear.

[image: Please check the error screen clip here]

This is the text code I put in jupyter notebook:

```
textdf = pd.DataFrame(["There are totally $1000 in account, $200 in case."],columns=['text'])

textdf.head()
```

The error output is like this which is not expected.

```
"There are totally  1000, 200 in case."
```

The expected result is just as plain text

```
"There are totally $1000 in account, $200 in case."
```

Comment: Try [r"There are totally $1000 in , $200 in case."]

Comment: Thank, I just tried, it does not works

Comment: I have also tried u" ", b" ", they are not work either.

Comment: If it works like MathJax normally works, putting a backslash before each dollar sign should work. It's worth a try, at least.

Comment: Yes!! The backslash works!!! Thank you!!!     Now I need to figure a way out how to put backslash in front of each $ in all the text extries in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You ran into a bug in Jupyter. `$...$` in a cell is used to denote MathMode. You can escape it to get what you want:

```
textdf = pd.DataFrame(["There are totally \$1000 in account, \$200 in case."],columns=['text'])
```

File a bug with the Jupyter Notebook team.

Comment: worked on my end...  
import pandas as pd
textdf = pd.DataFrame(["There are totally \$1000 in account, \$200 in case."],columns=['text'])
In [3]:
textdf
Out[3]:

text
0
There are totally $1000 in account, $200 in ...